# Multiuser - can process of background user kept running?

Tags: user-account, macos

On my Mac I use three user accounts. From what I understand when I'm logged in as one the processes of the other accounts are suspended. I switch between them with fast user switching.

My question is - can one assure that some processes keep running? Searching I found a few hints how to do on command line - but I'm considering to let a graphic application - like Steam - update itself for one user, and work as another user at the same time.

Comment: A somewhat related newer question is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382826/do-programs-keep-running-on-macos-when-user-switches-account

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm confident your premise is false.  When another user logs in to Mac OS X using the fast user switching, the GUI processes of other users are **not** suspended, but do continue to run in the background.  As long as you don't **log out** of the other accounts, their Finder process and programs launched as that user should continue to run in the background.

For instance, as I type this with my primary `cwrea` account on my Mac mini, I have another `sampleuser` account logged in (at the same time), and that user has a Safari window open that is playing a YouTube video.  *Right now.*

Then, if I load Activity Monitor while having my account `cwrea` in the foreground and select to view *"Other User Processes"*, Activity Monitor is reporting consistent ~8% CPU usage by a specific process named "PluginProcess" **owned by the `sampleuser` account.**

Moreover, if I switch back to `sampleuser`'s login session via fast user switching, the video is at a time location beyond where I left it, consistent with where it would be if I hadn't switched to my main account in the interim.

For what it's worth, the *sound* (and *video*, obviously) of the other background login session are *suppressed*, in that I don't hear or see either, but I can't find any evidence that graphical programs necessarily are suspended or cease operating in the background.

Comment: That would be a relief. I will run a few tests if this also holds when I have some "demanding" program. But then I'll mark this a solution.